# How to convert the datetime.date to Date.UTC using python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, highcharts, flask

I'm using highchart to create chart, the chart take this as argument and to see the full tuple is here: [highcharts jsonp](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?)

```
?([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,24),0.8924],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,25),0.8925],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,26),0.8955],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,28),0.9113],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,29),0.8900],
[Date.UTC(2015,5,30),0.8950]
]);
```

From my `PostgreSQL` database using `python` I get this result.

```
([
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 9), 345], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 8), 453], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 7), 467], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 6), 938], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 5), 393], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 4), 498], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 3), 334], 
[datetime.date(2016, 5, 2), 849]
])
```

How to format the results to match the the highcharts argument by converting the `datetime.date` to `Date.UTC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should calculate javascript timestamps (time in milliseconds since 01.01.1970) in Python from the dates - server-side.

or

send only dates (e.g. as strings) and parse it into required JS timestamps in JS - client-side.

Do not send functions - send string (date) or a number (timestamp).

Comment: Exactly! it did works like charm by converting the datetime to milliseconds  using `int(datetime_object.strftime("%s")) * 1000 `